# Sending some information via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm making a proyect which envolves bluetooth communication between a phone with Android and a little robot with Arduino. I want to send commands to the robot from the phone and I wanna recieve some status information like temperature, battery remaining charge and the robot will be integrated with a webcam... so I wanna send this images from the webcam to the phone. Is it possible???? Or I'm just like crazy and need another microcontroller (by the way I'm using the Atmega328p-pu that comes with the duemilanove) or another way to communicate them to handle all this "channels" of information. Could I multiplex it or decode it??????

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible with Arduino because data transfer is too slow
http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1226951266

I'd look at http://beagleboard.org/ which is a low-cost, fan-less single-board computer or what they use in robots like this one: http://www.bilibot.com/node/36

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is possible, but I'm not sure if Arduino can actually handle a Serial camera inbound data and the bluetooth serial outbound data with acceptable performance..

As "webcam" you would need something like this: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10061

Since you will need a Bluetooth module, you will use two serial ports, one for camera input, and other for Bluetooth communication, therefore check if your Arduino do have at least two serial inputs.

Here you can find the sensor shield and the Bluetooth module (ps. you may find on eBay for half the price):

http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=45&product_id=360

http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=V5&product_id=264

Take some time to read the data sheet and documentation from all these modules and good luck.

Comment: I think I better use an android phone to send the images via WiFi (hope that I can) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh.. sure you can, and it is way easier.